# Where is the BF Injection in GTA 3?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iii

I am completing the car garage missions in Shoreside Vale. The last car they expect is BF Injection. However, I am unable to find it.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to various forums and articles it should be located outside an apartment block in Hepburn Heights.

> You can only get hold of the BF Injection after completing the mission 'Sayonara Salvatore'. This is the first mission for Asuka on Staunton Island.
>
> After completing this mission, the BF Injection will appear outside an apartment block in Hepburn Heights. Directly behind your Portland Hideout. It will only be there at night when Joey Leone is not at work.
>
> <sub>[G-Unleashed, BF Injection](http://www.g-unleashed.com/index.php?cat=14&pid=110)</sub>

It should be located at number 10 in the following image.

[image: GTA 3 map]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I got the same answer from many people, just without the time hitch. Your answer really helped me